# Tag com nome errado

Tags: debate

Percebi que a tag [php-unit](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-unit) foi indevidamente nomeada. Deveria ser [phpunit](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpunit).

Como devemos proceder caso vejamos uma tag errada?

Comment: Não existe isso não :P

Comment: você consertou :p

Comment: @bigown aproveito e peço que faço o mesmo nesta `android-recycler-view` que deve ser `android-recyclerview`. (Sim eu sei que foi eu que a criei :$ )

Comment: @ramaral feito.

Answer (score 1):

Se for erro de digitação, do tipo `phpuniy` ou `php-unit`, eu faria o seguinte:

1. Incluiria um comentário para o autor da pergunta, avisando o erro.
2. Sinalizaria a questão, avisando os moderadores do erro.

Outros tipos de erros seriam mais complicados.

Se alguém incluir, por exemplo, a tag: `prompt-shell`, antes de qualquer coisa, teria que:

1. Analizar a pergunta
2. Pesquisar o assunto/tag até ter certeza do que se trata.

Caso não encontrasse nada sobre a tag duvidosa:

3. Sinalizar para os moderadores, indicando que é algo que nem o Google sabe do que se trata.

Não sei se deixaria comentário.

Comment: Não precisa esperar o autor corrigir, qualquer usuário da comunidade pode remover as tags inválidas e troca-las pelas corretas, mesmo que ainda não existam são criadas na hora, então após removida de todas perguntas a antiga deixará de existir em algumas semanas, o sistema faz a limpeza. O Wallace abriu a questão porque um moderador pode mudar a tag de multiplas perguntas com um comando simples, o que para nós usuários comuns é mais dificil. No caso o bigown já resolveu.